# Flipped picture after render in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I'm trying to make animation rendered in MTKView and experiencing a strange issue. In the simulator, I see flipped picture but on a device all is fine. I also render video with the same methods and picture has the same orientation on the device and the simulator.

Here is the most simplified example which reproduces my issue:

```swift
class TestVC: UIViewController {
    var output: MTKView!
    let device: MTLDevice
    let context: CIContext
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let queue: MTLCommandQueue?
    let image: CIImage

    init() {
        let defaultDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        self.device = defaultDevice
        self.context = CIContext(mtlDevice: defaultDevice)
        self.queue = defaultDevice.makeCommandQueue()
        self.image = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "lena.png")!)!
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        makeOutputView()
    }

    func makeOutputView() {
        let side = min(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height) * 0.9
        let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: side, height: side)
        output = MTKView(frame: viewFrame, device: device)
        view.addSubview(output)
        output.center = view.center
        output.framebufferOnly = false
        output.delegate = self
    }
}

extension TestVC: MTKViewDelegate {
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {}

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        let buffer = queue?.makeCommandBuffer()
        guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else { return }
        let dpi = UIScreen.main.nativeScale
        let width = view.bounds.width * dpi
        let height = view.bounds.height * dpi
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        let extent = image.extent
        let xScale = extent.width > 0 ? width  / extent.width  : 1
        let yScale = extent.height > 0 ? height / extent.height : 1
        let scale = max(xScale, yScale)
        let tx = (width - extent.width * scale) / 2
        let ty = (height - extent.height * scale) / 2
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: scale, b: 0, c: 0, d: scale, tx: tx, ty: ty)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform",
                              parameters: ["inputImage": image, "inputTransform": transform])!
        let scaledImage = filter.outputImage!
        context.render(scaledImage,
                       to: drawable.texture,
                       commandBuffer: buffer,
                       bounds: rect,
                       colorSpace: colorSpace)
        buffer?.present(drawable)
        buffer?.commit()
    }
}
```

And that's what I see:
[image]

Comment: This feels like a Simulator bug. My understanding is that the current beta of Xcode 11.4 enables GPU frame capture for Metal, so you might be able to use that to get some insight into where things are going wrong and find a workaround.

Comment: @warrenm Does it mean I have to flip photo only to render to video and keep original orientation to render to MTKView? It works for me but I want to figure out why it's happening

Comment: Are you going through CoreImage to render your video frames? Or do you have a different rendering path for that?

Comment: Yep. I'm going to use CoreImage to make changes on an image and render it after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has to do with the simulator using the GPU on your Mac which uses a different coordinate system. A quick workaround is to flip the image when running it in the simulator.

```swift
var scaledImage = filter.outputImage!
    
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    scaledImage = scaledImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1))
        .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: scaledImage.extent.height))
#endif

context.render(scaledImage,
          to: drawable.texture,
          commandBuffer: buffer,
          bounds: rect,
          colorSpace: colorSpace)
 buffer?.present(drawable)
 buffer?.commit()
```